# Vim errorformat: using %D to change directory

Tags: vim, errorformat

I'm struggling to find the right Vim `errorformat` to use when the current directory is a sibling of the directory with the file with the error. For example:

```
errorformat
errorformat/model
errorformat/spec
```

Vim's `makeprg` option is set to execute a file in `errorformat/spec`. I run make from `errorformat/model`. Vim is set up to use the current file's directory as the working directory.

To test, I'm running the following in `errorformat/model/errorformat.vim`

```
set makeprg=ruby\ ~/errorformat/spec/errorformat_spec.rb
let &efm="%D%f,%f:%l"
make!
copen
```

As you can see, that runs a Ruby file in the sibling directory which simply does

```
puts %{errorformat}
puts %{./spec/errorformat_spec.rb:1}
exit 5
```

The desired effect is that when I run the spec from a different directory, Vim will use the `%D` in the `errorformat` to let me open the spec file. But it's not working. In particular, I just can't seem to get `%D%f` to do what I expect. When I run this test, the QuickFix window shows

```
|| errorformat
|| ./spec/errorformat_spec.rb:1
```

The double bars are indicating that the `%D%f` part of the `errorformat` isn't recognizing the output. This also seems to prevent the next line from being interpreted by the `%f:%l` part.

There must be something very simple I'm missing!

Comment: Can you show what is the output of the error file you are trying to parse ? Is that not a probleme of delimiters (between %D and %f)?

Comment: The output I'm trying to parse is

    `errorformat`

    `./spec/errorformat_spec.rb:1`

I don't seem to be able to put this output on separate lines in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the order of the errorformat. The `%D%f` part needed to go **after** the `%f:%l` part.